# Add columns dynamically in JFace TableViewer

Tags: dynamic, swt, jface, provider, tableviewer

Within my project I'm reading in a CSV file and want to display it in SWT using a JFace `TableViewer`. Obviously enough the number of columns can vary from file to file, so I don't know how many columns there are beforehand.

My code that reads a file in, looks something like this:

```
final CSVDataInput in = new CSVDataInput(comboLocation.getText(), separators[selection]);
final Iterator<String[]> it = in.iterator();
final List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();

while (it.hasNext()) {

    data.add(it.next());
    count++;

}
```

I'm now a little bit lost in regards to passing this data on to a `TableViewer` in a clean way. I would like to know whether there are predefined content and/or label providers for such a case. It seems pretty basic to me, but so far I couldn't find anything suiting my case out of the box. I fiddled around with `ITableLabelProvider` for quite a while, but this doesn't seem right.

So what would be the best way to tackle this?

The way I'm doing it right now is to define an custom `ColumnLabelProvider`. This looks like something like this:

```
private class CSVColumnLabelProvider extends ColumnLabelProvider {

    private int column;

    public CSVColumnLabelProvider(int column) {

        this.column = column;

    }

    @Override
    public String getText(Object element) {

        return ((String[]) element)[column];

    }

}
```

I then have to assign an instance of this class to each column, e.g.:

```
tableViewerColumn.setLabelProvider(new CSVColumnLabelProvider(column++));
```

I don't think this is a particularly nice solution, and I'm probably missing the forest for all of the trees, because this feels like a problem with a cleaner solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that `ColumnLabelProvider` or the `ITableLabelProvider` are the only solutions that apply here. So I think this is fine.

Comment: I could use your example and instead of an array as element I had an object. Instead of the column index, I saved the property name in the `ColumnLabelProvider` and could invoke the correct method with reflection. Your approach was the best I could find.